# Cant return component after request to server - MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, axios, mern

im validating the route `/users` using router, with render:

```
 <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path = "/" exact component = {Home}></Route>
            <Route path = "/login" component = {Login}></Route>
            <Route path = "/users" render = {verify_session}></Route>
            <Route component = {Not_found}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

so each time accesing to `/users` it will run the function verify_session, this one:

```
function verify_session() {
    axios.get("api/cook/login/verify_session").then((response) => {
        if (response.data === 404) {
            return <Redirect to = "/login"></Redirect>
        }else {
            return <Users></Users>
        }
    });
}
```

this is in the backend:

```
router.get("/verify_session", (request, response) => {
    if (request.session.user != undefined) {
        response.json(200);
    }else {
        response.json(404);
    }
})
```

it works because when i enter to `/users` without loggin i can see 404, but it isnt returning the component, if its using a simple validation:

```
function verify_session() {
   let i = 1;
   if (i >= 1) {
      return <Redirect to = "/login"></Redirect>
    }else {
      return <Users></Users>
    }
}
```

this way works, but with request get doesnt return anything

Answer (score 1):

This function won't render anything because it doesn't actually return anything. It makes an asynchronous call to an API and those `return` statements return stuff to the axios' `then` function instead of the `verify_session` function.

```
function verify_session() {
    axios.get("api/cook/login/verify_session").then((response) => {
        if (response.data === 404) {
            return <Redirect to = "/login"></Redirect>
        }else {
            return <Users></Users>
        }
    });
}
```

This function works because, well, it returns a component right away:

```
function verify_session() {
   let i = 1;
   if (i >= 1) {
      return <Redirect to = "/login"></Redirect>
    }else {
      return <Users></Users>
    }
}
```

Here is how you will need to change your `verify_session` function for it work with an API call:

```
function verify_session() {
  const [verified, setVerified] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("api/cook/login/verify_session").then((response) => {
        if (response.data === 404) {
            setVerified(false);
        }else {
            setVerified(true);
        }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {verified === null ? (
        <div>Verifying...</div>
      ) : verified ? (
        <Users></Users>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to = "/login"></Redirect>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

And then use it like so: `<Route path = "/users" render = {verify_session}></Route>`

Here you create a state inside the verify function that gets updated based on what you get from the API and then render what it needs to render only after the API call is complete.